# Can't render documents from Mongo DB (w/ Mongoose, Node and Express)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a test-website running on localhost:3000 with a local mongo db as well. It was working fine when all of a sudden I can't seem to get the documents from the db to render on the website any more. There's a bunch of things already working which I'll list first:

- I have installed mongo, mongoose and all other required packages both globally and saved in the package.json (perhaps there has been an update to one of the packages and now the local and global version don't match?).
- The database exists (on /data) and has documents which I can find when I run 'mongo' in my terminal.
- The connection works both in the app.js file (code below) as well as throwing no error when I run 'mongod'.
- I even tried it with a brand new db which containted a new collection and for which I made a test page that should render the files. This is the code that I'm showing as it is much simpler than my website with multiple pages (and lots of Node). This test website is also not working.
- I'm using EJS to render the javascript on the website but that does not seem to be the problem.

Frustrating the hell out of me!

Now for some code:

**TEST APP.JS**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mongo = require('mongo');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));



mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ScaryMovieNight', {
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
    useCreateIndex: true  
},
function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.info('connection ok');
    }
   });

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let testSchema = new Schema ({
    title: String
});

let Test = mongoose.model('test', testSchema);

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {

    Test.find()
        .then(picture => {
            res.render('test', {movies: picture})
    // Also tried res.json(picture) which returns an empty object
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Test is working on port 3000.')
});
```

**TEST PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    This is test.
    <li>
    <% movies.forEach(picture => { %>
        <ul>Test Title Is : <%= picture.title %></ul>
    <% }) %>
    </li>
</body>
</html>
```

**MONGO DB IN THE SHELL**

```
    > show dbs
    ScaryMovieNight  0.000GB
    admin            0.000GB
    config           0.000GB
    local            0.000GB
    > use ScaryMovieNight
    switched to db ScaryMovieNight
    > db.movies.find()
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5ee0958d569eb17e88a8c2aa"), "title" : "Evil Dead 2", "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5ee177496a0f9090f811be71"), "title" : "Green Room",  "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5ee26794d27e52a16c3ab910"), "title" : "Alien", "__v" : 0 }
    { "_id" : ObjectId("5ee7fee3f1a65aac3aa87dcb"), "title" : "Aliens" }
```

**MONGOD CONNECTION**

```
    Macintosh-14:TestDB dariustimmer$ mongod
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.643+0200 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.683+0200 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=8121 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Macintosh-14.local
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.7
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 51d9fe12b5d19720e72dcd7db0f2f17dd9a19212
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.688+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.689+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
    2020-06-19T00:30:50.690+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=3584M,cache_overflow=(file_max=0M),session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress],
    2020-06-19T00:30:51.986+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1592519451:986196][8121:0x7fffa59013c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 11 through 12
    2020-06-19T00:30:52.254+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1592519452:254712][8121:0x7fffa59013c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 12 through 12
    2020-06-19T00:30:52.506+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1592519452:506030][8121:0x7fffa59013c0], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 11/42368 to 12/256
    2020-06-19T00:30:52.635+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1592519452:635022][8121:0x7fffa59013c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 11 through 12
    2020-06-19T00:30:52.797+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1592519452:797815][8121:0x7fffa59013c0], txn-recover: Recovering log 12 through 12
    2020-06-19T00:30:52.854+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1592519452:854550][8121:0x7fffa59013c0], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.496+0200 I  RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.506+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Timestamp monitor starting
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.509+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.509+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.509+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: This server is bound to localhost.
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Remote systems will be unable to connect to this server. 
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Start the server with --bind_ip <address> to specify which IP 
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          addresses it should serve responses from, or with --bind_ip_all to
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          bind to all interfaces. If this behavior is desired, start the
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          server with --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 to disable this warning.
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.510+0200 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.520+0200 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.system.replset as collection version: <unsharded>
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.522+0200 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Flow Control is enabled on this deployment.
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.522+0200 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.roles as collection version: <unsharded>
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.522+0200 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection admin.system.version as collection version: <unsharded>
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.525+0200 I  SHARDING [initandlisten] Marking collection local.startup_log as collection version: <unsharded>
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.525+0200 I  FTDC     [initandlisten] Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture with directory '/data/db/diagnostic.data'
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.526+0200 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheRefresh] Marking collection config.system.sessions as collection version: <unsharded>
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.527+0200 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.527+0200 I  NETWORK  [listener] Listening on 127.0.0.1
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.527+0200 I  NETWORK  [listener] waiting for connections on port 27017
    2020-06-19T00:30:53.527+0200 I  SHARDING [LogicalSessionCacheReap] Marking collection config.transactions as collection version: <unsharded>
    2020-06-19T00:30:54.003+0200 I  SHARDING [ftdc] Marking collection local.oplog.rs as collection version: <unsharded>
    2020-06-19T00:30:57.328+0200 I  NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:50163 #1 (1 connection now open)
    2020-06-19T00:30:57.329+0200 I  NETWORK  [conn1] received client metadata from 127.0.0.1:50163 conn1: { driver: { name: "nodejs|Mongoose", version: "3.5.9" }, os: { type: "Darwin", name: "darwin", architecture: "x64", version: "16.7.0" }, platform: "'Node.js v12.18.0, LE (unified)", version: "3.5.9|5.9.19" }
```

I have tried a million things but can't seem to render these movie titles any more. Any help would be greatly appreciated it's been a few very frustrating days..

Answer (score 0):

In mongoose, you have called your model "test", but the collection in MongoDb is called "movies". So your search returns nothing. Try changing your code in your express app:

```
let Test = mongoose.model('Movie', testSchema);
```

(This is the minimal change to make it work. If you want to further develop this app, it would be better to call everything 'Movie'.)

Comment: It worked! And yes, in my original app I have defintely called everything Movie. I now also figured out why it wouldn't load there. I had redefined my Schema and named something wrong there as well. Boy am I glad this is worked out.

So am I correct in understanding that the db should always be named plural (eg. movies) and then the model show be a single name with capital (eg. Movie)?

Answer (score 0):

Install MongoDB with command `npm i mongodb@4.14.0`. Render is not working for latest version.